# Svg namespaces for xlink:href in use

Tags: javascript, svg

I want to create an svg-element with `use` referring to icon in svg sprite:

```js
var svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg")
var use = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "use")
use.setAttributeNS("http://w3.org/1999/xlink", "href", "/sprite.svg#some-icon")
svg.append(use)
document.body.append(svg)
```

The markup is created

```html
<svg><use href="/sprite.svg#some-icon"></use></svg>
```

But nothing is shown unless I execute

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML
```

I understand that I'm doing something wrong with namespaces, but don't understand what exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your namespace string is wrong.  It needs to be the following *exactly*.

```
http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink
```